# gnuplot warning: Skipping data file with no valid points, using a very simple file.dat

Tags: linux, plot, gnuplot

i'd like to understand the use of "index" command to plot only some groups of datas or for example to plot every group but with different titles etc..

i started with an easy example: in the file prova.dat i have the following text (i've already checked that there are not white records a the end of the lines):

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4

1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
```

then i use this code to plot data from 'prova.dat':

```
 set term postscript  eps enhanced font 'Times-Roman,24'
 set output 'prova.eps'
 set key right top
 set xrange [1:5]
 set yrange [1:5]
 plot 'prova.dat' index 0 w lines title columnheader(1), \
      'prova.dat' index 1 w lines title columnheader(1)
```

but i get the following warning:

```
warning: Skipping data file with no valid points
```

thus in the .eps produced i have no plots but just the axis (correctly formatted).

i've read also other posts but i can't find a solution.

thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have **two** empty lines between the two data blocks?

Comment: You need two empty lines between data blocks to make the index work. If you just add one more line, you should be done.

Comment: Gnuplot makes a difference between datasets (selected via `index`) and blocks of data (selected via `every`) Read `help index` and `help every`. Using the latter you can plot your data without changing the file

Comment: now it works, thanks a lot! :D